# Nginx Rewrite Rule for replacing space/whitespace with Hyphen and convert URL to lowercase

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

How can I convert all my URLs to lower case and replace space `" "` with `-` hyphen in NGINX ??

Answer (score 3):

I searched few things and I found that **perl scripts** can help us in this matter. So I am sharing a solution here. How feasible the solution is or is it a best practice, perhaps an NGINX expert can shed some light to it.

First in your `nginx.conf` add the following perl script in `http block`

```
# Include the perl module
    perl_modules perl/lib;

# Define function
    perl_set $uri_lowercase 'sub {
    my $r = shift;
    my $uri = $r->uri;
    $uri = lc($uri);        # lowercase conversion

    # replace space with - hyphen

    my $search = " ";
    my $replace = "-";
    $uri =~ s/$search/$replace/ig;


    return $uri;
}';
```

The reason I wanted to keep in `nginx.conf` coz I needed to use this function in multiple vhosts.

Now in your **Vhost files** write these lines

```
# In case you want your static content's URL should not be converted to lowercase
# Rewrite skip check jpg uppercase characters. leave it blank no processing is required.
location ~ [A-Z]*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|flv|swf|css|js) {
}

# now check for uppercase and convert it into lowercase
location ~ [A-Z] {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host$uri_lowercase;
}

# Finally check the whitepaces and replace them
location ~ [\s+] {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host$uri_lowercase;
}
```

If anybody else can guide me to a better approach I'll be happy to apply that.
Hope it helps.